# What is `-l` flag in macos ssh-agent?

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-agent

When I search PID of manualy started ssh-agent I also found process `/usr/bin/ssh-agent -l`. I try to find description in man but I can't. What is the `-l` flag and can it be useful?

Comment: If I recall correctly, there are occasions where it is convenient to use `ssh-agent` as a user's login "shell". The `login` program invokes the login shell with the `-l` option, so `ssh-agent` accepts it without actually doing anything with it.

Comment: Looks like I did *not* recall correctly :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-240.40.1/openssh/ssh-agent.c.auto.html), it seems to be an undocumented flag that is related to `ssh-agent`'s integration into macOS' `launchd`, namely how the unix file socket used to communicate with other processes is created (`l_flag` is set if `-l` is given on the command line):

```c
#ifdef __APPLE_LAUNCHD__
    if (l_flag) {
        int *fds = NULL;
        size_t count = 0;
        result = launch_activate_socket("Listeners", &fds, &count);

        if (result != 0 || fds == NULL || count < 1) {
            errno = result;
            perror("launch_activate_socket()");
            exit(1);
        }

        size_t i;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            new_socket(AUTH_SOCKET, fds[i]);
        }

        if (fds)
            free(fds);

        goto skip2;
    } else {
 #endif
    prev_mask = umask(0177);
    sock = unix_listener(socket_name, SSH_LISTEN_BACKLOG, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        /* XXX - unix_listener() calls error() not perror() */
        *socket_name = '\0'; /* Don't unlink any existing file */
        cleanup_exit(1);
    }
#ifdef __APPLE_LAUNCHD__
    }
#endif
```

I'm not familiar with `launchd`'s concepts, but checking the configuration of the ssh-agent service shows a corresponding section:

```bash
$ launchctl print gui/1010/com.openssh.ssh-agent
[...]
sockets = {
        "Listeners" = {
            type = stream
            path = /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.4crvXaBll8/Listeners
            secure key = SSH_AUTH_SOCK
            owner uid = 1010
            group id = 0

            sockets = {
                26 (bytes to read)
            }

            active = 1
            passive = 1
            bonjour = 0
            ipv4v6 = 0
            receive_packet_info = 0
        }
    }
[...]
```